# Android Number formatting exception when taking information from edit text 

Tags: android, google-maps, exception, android-edittext, numberformatexception

here i take the latude and longtude from the user then i converted it into integer and here is the problem the log cat msg is :

unable to convert 30.01 into int !   then i enter the lat and lon into my table in the database:

```
  public class newMission extends Activity 
  implements OnClickListener{
SQLiteDatabase sql;
EditText e1,e2,e3,e4;
Button b;
MaptoDo obj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent in =getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.newmission);
    e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edn1);
    e2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edn2);
    e3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edn3);
    e4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edn4);
    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnew);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    obj=new MaptoDo();
    sql=openOrCreateDatabase("db",0, null);
    sql.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Mission" +
            "" +
            " (emp integer REFERENCES Employee2 (password)," +
            "oper_n text,cust_n text,lat double," +
            "long double,oper_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)");
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String opN=e1.getText().toString();
    String cuN=e2.getText().toString();
    String lats=e3.getText().toString();
    String lons=e4.getText().toString();
     try {
  int lat=Integer.parseInt(lats);
  int lon=Integer.parseInt(lons);
  sql.execSQL("insert into Mission (oper_n,cust_n,lat,long)values('"+opN+"','"+cuN+"',"+lat+","+lon+");");
  Toast.makeText(this,"Data Inserted",2000).show();
  obj.addMission(lat, lon); 
    //add to ToDo list too 
}catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Valid Data",2000).show();
}}
```

}

Comment: As an aside: be sure to read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Yes: you're changing the question after people answered it. Please note that these sites are not forums; we expect questions and their answers to be of some value for future visitors too. Also, the current title sounds like "Please help me debug"—not useful for future visitors at all.

Comment: @Arjan ok i get what you want to say ...thank you for the advice i will delete this question ok ?

Comment: Err, no...! It's even worse to delete stuff that people have put effort in to answer. Just change the question back into its original state. (Apart from that: [you cannot delete it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `double` datatype first.

```
double dLat=Double.parseDouble(lats);
double dLon=Double.parseDouble(lons);
```

Then its a matter of getting the value before the decimal point:

```
int lat = (int)Math.floor(dLat);
int lon = (int)Math.floor(dLon);
```

Or if you want - you can run a regular expression on the input first to make sure it has digits [dot] digits otherwise the extraction of the inputs to numeric will fail, but having said that, that would be dependent on how the layout for the `EditText` has it set up for certain input types - `android:inputType` within the XML layout.

Comment: First Correction :changing my code from :
     int lat=Integer.parseInt(lats);
     int lon=Integer.parseInt(lons);  
to 
      double dLat=Double.parseDouble(lats);
      double dLon=Double.parseDouble(lons);
then removing the object of the MapToDo class

Answer (score 0):

You cant convert the string "30.01" into `int` without losing precision. Try parsing it into `float`.

```
float lat = Float.parseFloat(lats);
```

or use

```
double lat = Double.parseDouble(lats);
```

Comment: any one who saw your answer can vote up or down ...i did not vote down on your answer !

Comment: I did not downvote either, but: of course one can convert a floating point value (such as a double) into an integer. You'll just lose precision, 30.01 becoming 30. But if that's what you want, you can do it? So, *maybe* folks downvoted because you boldly said it can't be done? Also `parseDouble` gives `double` not `Double` when not autoboxing. That said: I guess the question asker did not truly want an integer indeed; even their database is not using an integer column.

Comment: And indeed, @Syamic actually commented to the accepted answer *"changing my code [...] to `double dLat=Double.parseDouble(lats)`"* like you wrote above. So, you were right: no `int` needed at all; beats me why people downvoted your answer then...